# Probability density function of $\text{exp}(-j(a+X))$ where $X\sim \text{Unif}[0,2\pi]$

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, random-variables

Assume that $X$ follows a uniform distribution $\text{Unif}[0,2\pi]$. How do we get a probability density function $f_Y(y)$ where $Y=\text{exp}(-j(a+X))$?

$j$ indicates the imaginary unit, $j^2=-1$.

Comment: Rewrite $Y$ as $\cos (a+X)-j \sin (a+X)$ and plot the values of a large (n=500) random sample.

Answer (score 1):

Densities need to be defined with respect to a particular measure.  For continuous, real-valued random variables, like your $X$, the usual measure is the Lebesgue measure, and given the density for $X$ with respect to this measure, $f_X(x)=1/2\pi, \,0\leq x <2\pi$, you can evaluate expectations of functions of $X$ using this density with integrals of the form:
$$E[h(X)] = \int_0^{2\pi} h(x)\,f_X(x)\,dx = \frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} h(x) dx$$
For a complex-valued random variable $Y$ with values restricted to a path in the complex plane (in this case, the unit circle), the density must be defined with respect to a non-zero measure on that path.

The obvious choice, it turns out, is to take the measure $\mu$ that's uniform on the unit circle with total mass $2\pi$.  With respect to this measure, $Y$ has constant density $f_Y(y)=1/2\pi,\,|y|=1$ (i.e., the same density as $X$ but defined on different support).  Expectations can be expressed as Lebesgue integrals using this density:
$$E[h(Y)]=\int_{|y|=1}h(y)f_Y(y)\mu(dy)$$
though in practice, you'd use a change of variable $y=e^{j\theta}$ to write:
$$E[h(Y)]=\int_0^{2\pi}h(e^{j\theta})\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}$$
which is basically equivalent to just writing the expectation in terms of $X$ and its density in the first place:
$$E[h(Y)]=E[h(e^{-j(a+X)})]=\int_0^{2\pi}h(e^{-j(a+x)})\frac{dx}{2\pi}$$